# Evitar nombres repetidos en arreglo c++

Tags: c++, string, array

Como parte de mi asignatura de estructura de datos nos han dejado el siguiente ejercicio:

> Crear una estructura de datos que permita almacenar los datos de las compras totales de clientes de un almacen.
>   Se desea almacenar la siguiente información: Numero de la factura, Fecha, Almacen, Cliente, Ciudad, Sexo, Valorcompras.
>
> Cree un arreglo que permita diligenciar la información de N clientes y posteriormente, implemente (puede ser usando un menu) las siguientes opciones:
>
> 1. Mostrar el total del valor de compras hecho por los clientes, y el promedio de las compras
> 2. Ordenar el arreglo y mostrarlo de acuerdo con los siguientes criterios:
>
>    - *2.1* Por clientes
>    - *2.2* Por almacen
>    - *2.3* Por valor compras (descendentemente)
> 3. Mostrar un resumen que diga:
>
>    - *3.1* Cuantas ventas se hicieron en cada ciudad
>    - *3.2* Cuantos clientes hay en cada ciudad
> 4. Incluir una opcion que permita hacer busquedas en el vector por ciudad.  Se ingresara el nombre de la ciudad y el sistma deberá devolver todas las ventas hechas en esa ciudad.

La cuestión es que ya hemos realizado la mayor parte del código, el programa es capaz de leer los datos necesarios, realizar las operaciones, los ordenamientos, etc...
Pero no hemos podido crear el algoritmo para contar la cantidad de clientes que se tienen en cada ciudad, ya que el programa debe ser capaz de reconocer cuando un cliente se ha repetido en la ciudad para no volver a registrarlo como un cliente diferente; o sea, que si un cliente realiza, por ejemplo, 2 compras en la misma ciudad, el programa lo registre como un solo cliente, no como 2.
  Aquí está el código que utilizamos para contar las ventas (la parte sencilla, ya que no hay excepciones) y la estructura que creamos:

```
struct venta{//la estructura que utilizamos
string numfactura;//numero de factura 
string fecha;
string almacen;
string cliente;
int ciudad;//la ciudad tiene unos cuantos valores predefinidos
float valorcompras;
}vector[50];

for (int i=0;i<N;i++){//Este ciclo recorre el vector en busca de las coincidencias
                if (vector[i].ciudad==1){
                ventasm+=1;//cuando ciudad es 1, se le suma 1 al contador de la ciudad 1.
                clientesm+=1;//esto es lo que tenemos, si el cliente se repite varias veces, este algorito lo contará como clientes diferentes. esto es lo que necesitamos cambiar.
                }
                else if (vector[i].ciudad==2){//exactamente lo mismo pero con la segunda ciudad
                ventabq+=1;
                clientebq+=1;
                }
            }
```

Espero de verdad haber sido conciso y que ustedes puedan ayudarme a resolver este problema. gracias de antemano.

Comment: hola @Robinquintero , bienvenido a StackOverFlow en español, sabes deberias de intentar de hacerlo solo tu "tarea", al parecer no hiciste ningun esfuerzo en hacerlos, al hacer tu "tarea" podrias encontrar ciertos errores que no puedas solucionar con lo que enseñan en clases, es ahi donde debes de acudir a este sitio.

Comment: Disculpame, tengo un caso parecido. Pero ponele, yo tengo un array de 64 contenedores, donde cada uno tiene guardado el cliente, y procedencia. Tengo que mostrar en una funcion cuantos contenedores tengo por cliente. Pero no se, como hacer para que me recorra y a la vez segun cada cliente vaya iniciando un contador, y me devuelva cuantos contenedores tiene cada uno. Como podria realizar el codigo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si tenéis que contar el número de clientes que han comprado en cada ciudad y además saber si ese cliente ya ha comprado ahí, necesitáis algo donde almacenar los clientes que ya han comprado, por ejemplo un vector.

### Esta sería la idea:

Tu `struct` ahora quedaría así:

```
struct venta{       //la estructura que utilizamos
string numfactura;  //numero de factura 
string fecha;
string almacen;
string[] clientes;   //aquí guardáis todos los clientes distintos
//El siguiente es el número de clientes distintos, esto os lo podríais
//ahorrar si quisierais trabajando con vuestro vector cliente, ya que al  
//final cuenta el número de elementos que hay en el vector
int numClientes;    
int ciudad;         //la ciudad tiene unos cuantos valores predefinidos
float valorcompras;
}vector[50];
```

Tu código quedaría parecido a algo así:

```
for (int i=0;i<N;i++){//Este ciclo recorre el vector en busca de las coincidencias
                if (vector[i].ciudad==1){
                ventasm+=1;//cuando ciudad es 1, se le suma 1 al contador de la ciudad 1.
                if(!clienteEnVectorClientes(cliente)) //esta función simplemente busca un elemento en un vector
                numClientes+=1; //incrementamos nuestro contador de clientes diferentes
                }
                else if (vector[i].ciudad==2){//exactamente lo mismo pero con la segunda ciudad
                ventabq+=1;
                clientebq+=1;
                }
            }
```

#### Ejemplo de clienteEnVectorClientes

```
bool clienteEnVectorClientes(string cliente)
{
    for(int i=0; i<numClientes;i++)
    {
        if(cliente==clientes[i])
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
  return false;
}
```

> Cada vez que se vaya a guardar un cliente, habría que llamar a esta función para saber si ya está. Si está, no se hace nada, si no está se añade y se incrementa numClientes.

Espero que te sirva y te ayude. Creo que lo mejor es que **tu mismo lo intentes**. No obstante, no está mal que preguntes si te atascas.

Comment: Muchas gracias compañero, voy a intentarlo.
Y pues si acudí a StackOverflow fue porque llevaba unas 6 horas estancado slo con esto, y con algo de vergüenza ya que sé que es algo muy sencillo.

Comment: Cualquier cosa. Aquí estamos